# Alternative to AbsoluteLayout in "multi layer" layouts

Tags: android, layout, positioning, android-relativelayout, absolutelayout

I am developing an android app with a layout that includes buttons arranged around a circular element. As the corners of said element would overlap with other buttons, the recommended layout types (LinearLayout etc.) are not a viable option.

However, I want to do this right and not use the deprecated AbsoluteLayout. So far, though, I see no alternatives. Are there?

Answer (score 1):

Relative layouts would probably work depending on how you want to place your buttons.
It allows you to place the buttons to the left/right of each other or above/under, so placing them around a circular element should be possible.

Here's the link to the android documentation for [relative layouts](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html).